# Execute Scalar to trap error in case of no records returned

Tags: vb.net, ado.net

I have got this code below:

```
Dim lJobName As String = ""
SQLCommand.CommandText = "Select JobName from Jobs where Id = @Id "
SQLCommand.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@Id", SqlDbType.Int))
SQLCommand.Parameters(0).Value = var_id
lJobName = SQLCommand.ExecuteScalar()
```

Issue how to catch if no records are found?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I try to avoid comparing a string to Nothing, even though it does work in VB.

The Visual Basic .NET runtime evaluates Nothing as an empty string; that is, "". The .NET Framework, however, does not, and will throw an exception whenever an attempt is made to perform a string operation on Nothing.

Plus pseudocoder's answer wont work as currently shown (oJobname is never set to anything)

```
Dim lJobName as String = String.Empty
Dim oJobName as object = SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar()

If oJobName Is Nothing Then
    'Do something with the error condition
Else
    lJobName = oJobName.ToString
End If
```

Comment: String.Empty is not the same thing as Nothing, which is why I didn't use `If String.IsNullOrEmpty(lJobName) Then`

Comment: Wow, major cut and paste error, i have changed my post to show what I intended.

Comment: I see what you're going for there.  Still, `String` holds a value of `Nothing` just fine.  The only reason not to use it is if you want to implement a pattern that would work well for non-nullable value types such as `Integer` or `Decimal`, which is exemplified by your answer.  You should really correct your inaccurate statement about "evaluates Nothing as an empty string" though.

Answer (score 4):

Whatever the manual says, comparing to Nothing does not work. So `If lJobName Is Nothing` will NOT be triggered when the result set is empty.

Comparing to DBNull.Value DID work for me:

```
If lJobName Is DBNull.Value Then
    'Do something with the error condition
Else
    'Do something with lJobName which contains a valid result.
End If
```

It is worth noting that when the result set is empty (i.e. no records were found), this is not an "error".

Answer (score 1):

I think it is possible to handle this situation in the statement of the query:

SELECT ISNULL(FieldID,"0") FROM TableName

and subsequently in the program validate the result:

if  then
   ......
else
   ......
endif

Answer (score 0):

ExecuteScalar() returns `Nothing` if there is an empty result set, which should be preserved when assigning into a string, so I would try this:

```
Dim lJobName as String = String.Empty
lJobName = SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar()
If lJobName Is Nothing Then
    'Do something with the error condition
Else
    'Do something with lJobName which contains a valid result.
End If
```

Of course this doesn't help you if you cause a SqlException, but it should handle the problem of no rows found in the result set.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx

Comment: Not really DBNull.Value. ExecuteScalar return `The first column of the first row in the result set, or a null reference (Nothing in Visual Basic)`

Comment: Thanks for correcting my inability to read documentation.  I updated my answer.

Comment: Yes better to use Is Nothing than IsDbNull also, lJobName = oJobName is an implicit conversion and will not work with option strict, better to call .ToString on oJobName