# ExecuteScalar returns nothing from stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio, stored-procedures, executescalar

I have a simple stored procedure that returns the *type_id* (int) as an OUTPUT parameter using the *type_name* (varchar(100)) as the input parameter. When I execute the stored procedure in SqlServer, it works fine and returns the appropriate *type_id*.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[intake_types_select_by_type_name]
    @type_name varchar(100),
    @type_id integer OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SET XACT_ABORT ON

    SELECT  @type_id = type_id
    FROM    intake_types
    WHERE   type_name = @type_name
END
```

However, when I call the stored procedure from a function in VisualStudio the parameter **@type_id** returns **Nothing**.

```
Public Shared Function sp_intake_types_select_by_type_name(ByVal conn As DBConnection, ByVal caseName As String) As Integer
    Dim sp As SqlCommand = conn.GetStoredProcedure("intake_types_select_by_type_name")
    With sp.Parameters
        .Add("@type_name", SqlDbType.VarChar, ParameterDirection.Input).Value = caseName
        .Add("@type_id", SqlDbType.Int)
        .Item("@type_id").Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
    End With
    sp.ExecuteScalar()
    If Not IsDBNull(sp.Parameters("@type_id").Value) Then
        Return sp.Parameters("@type_id").Value
    Else
        Return Nothing
    End If
End Function
```

I have spent hours searching the web for a solution and found nothing that helps. I have a similar stored procedure and function in a different project that uses the same coding and logic and it works fine (however it returns a *varchar* as the OUTPUT parameter). I have compared these two projects to see if I am missing something simple but no joy.

Comment: Did you tried `Dim result = sp.ExecuteScalar()`?

Comment: Every example I've seen does something like `TypeID = (Int32) sp.ExecuteScalar()`. Are you sure in your other project you are simply making a naked call to `sp.ExecuteScalar()`?

Comment: remove `.Item("@type_id").Direction = ParameterDirection.Output`, change `.Add("@type_id", SqlDbType.Int)` to `.Add("@type_id", SqlDbType.Int, ParameterDirection.Output)`, and change `ExecuteScalar` to `ExecuteNonQuery()`. I don't know if it will solve your problem but it's worth a try.

Comment: `ExecuteScalar` returns something ***IF*** you have a `SELECT` in your stored procedure that selects (and thus returns) exactly **one row, one column**. You on the other hand are **assigning** this value to an **output parameter** - this will ***NOT*** be returned by `ExecuteScalar`!

Comment: @Aaron Bertrand - Yes, it is making a naked call and working, but now I'm not sure why. I will be updating this one, too.

Comment: @Zohard Peled - tried that before and it didn't work. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @marc_s - great information! Thanks.

Comment: @AaronBertrand You have spotted the problem, unique to the default settings in VB.NET, where the availability of run-time type conversion (a.k.a. late binding) is invoked. `Option Strict On` disables that. [The many memes of meta: Option Strict On](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/273139/232762).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really should use [`Option Strict On`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs.aspx) and correct the problems it points out. At the moment, implicit conversions between data types are being performed which will make your code much slower and possibly error-prone.

I suggest the following:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[intake_types_select_by_type_name]
    @type_name varchar(100)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SET XACT_ABORT ON;

    SELECT  type_id
    FROM    intake_types
    WHERE   type_name = @type_name
END
```

And the function to call it:

```
Option Strict On
' ....'

Public Shared Function sp_intake_types_select_by_type_name(ByVal conn As DBConnection, ByVal caseName As String) As Integer
    Dim sp As SqlCommand = conn.GetStoredProcedure("intake_types_select_by_type_name")
    sp.Parameters.Add("@type_name", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = caseName

    Dim result As Object = sp.ExecuteScalar()

    If result Is Nothing Then
        Return -1 ' check for -1 in the calling code '
    Else
        Return CInt(result)
    End If

End Function
```

It is almost always good idea to specify the size of the SQL parameter so that the database can re-use the execution plan rather than making a new execution plan for each length of the parameters.

Please note that it is generally a bad idea to use one SQL connection for everything: you should use the connection then dispose of it as soon as its immediate use is done. It seems like a good idea at first, but it is fighting against the way that it is designed ([connection pooling](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca(v=vs.110).aspx) takes care of fast re-opening of connections).

Ref: [Execute Scalar to trap error in case of no records returned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13253718/1115360).

Comment: Andrew, thank you very much for the tips, excellent explanations, _and_ a working solution. The **Option Strict On** uncovered two more implicit conversions which I have fixed. I will be looking into using/disposing SQL connection next instead of using one SQL connection for everything. I really appreciate your time and great input!

Comment: @MichaelCallas You're welcome :) I strongly recommend setting Option Strict On as the default for new projects, if you haven't done that already. Regarding another of the answers in the post I linked to, I did actually test the VB snippet against a real database to confirm that `Is Nothing` works and `Is DbNull.Value` gives false results, just in case you read further.

Comment: Andrew, I have the default set for new projects but this is an inherited project so I am glad you pointed that out. I also read the link in your post so thanks for the follow-up. Good stuff to know.